# Understanding WCF reliable session retry behaviour

Tags: c#, wcf, ws-reliablemessaging

I have several questions about WCF reliable session reliability:

1. Does WCF re-serialize a message during a retry attempt?

   <strike>2. If 1 is correct - does it happen after message parameters were disposed or not?
    3. If 2 is correct - is there any way to identify message was sent for sure?</strike>

I could not yet figure that out via reflector.

**UPD 1:** I'm more interested with server return values. What happens to them?

**UPD 2:** When are message parameters (to be precise - server reply) disposed? Does it happen when appropriate acks are received?
Here is what I mean by disposing parameters:

```
at MyNamespace.MyReply.Dispose()
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.DisposeParametersCore()
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessageCleanup(MessageRpc&amp;amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&amp;amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc&amp;amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.DispatchAndReleasePump(RequestContext request, Boolean cleanThread, OperationContext currentOperationContext)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.HandleRequest(RequestContext request, OperationContext currentOperationContext)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.AsyncMessagePump(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.Utility.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
   at System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.Utility.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.InputQueue`1.AsyncQueueReader.Set(Item item)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.InputQueue`1.Dispatch()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.InputQueueChannel`1.Dispatch()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableReplySessionChannel.ProcessSequencedMessage(RequestContext context, String action, WsrmSequencedMessageInfo info)
...stack continues
```

I need to use it to dispose server reply (I have another SOF thread on why I came to this solution).

**UPD 3:** Issue I'm trying to solve is that it *seems* that my server reply is first disposed and then application attempts to serialize it. I'm 99% sure that I do not reuse same object anywhere else. Stacktraces are pretty ugly and big to post here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, WCF does *not* reserialize the message.

What happens is this (simplified): during a session, each message being sent from the client is being buffered on the client. By default, there is room for 32 messages (this can be tweaked; and there's also a buffer on the service side).

The message is then sent to the server, and if it gets there okay and is dispatched, the server send a confirmation and the client removes the message from the buffer.

However, if the client sent message #15 and #16, and then gets a confirmation for #16 (but not for #15), then message #15 is re-sent from the buffer.

There are quite a few options you can configure, like whether or not you want ordered delivery, how many times the client should retry sending a message and so forth.

Check out those articles and blog post for more information:

- [Introduction to Reliable Messaging with the Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480191.aspx)
- [WCF: Reliable Message Delivery](http://www.request-response.com/blog/PermaLink,guid,a6cb59e6-cbc2-4ce3-92b2-ea40bc5929f6.aspx)
- [How does Reliable Messaging work](http://www.lybecker.com/blog/2007/01/23/how-does-reliable-messaging-work/)
- [WCF Sessions and Reliable Messaging](http://www.lybecker.com/blog/2007/04/30/wcf-sessions-and-reliable-messaging/)
- [WCF Top To Bottom Screencast; Reliable Messaging](http://msevents.microsoft.com/CUI/WebCastEventDetails.aspx?culture=en-US&EventID=1032344354&CountryCode=US)

Hope this helps clarify things a bit

UPDATE on responses: taken from the first article (on MSDN) I referenced:

> If we assume having a Request/Response
>   communication pattern, the response
>   needs to be delivered just as reliably
>   as the request and therefore the
>   responding party must implement an
>   initiator mechanism that is very
>   similar to what the requesting party
>   implements for the original requests.
>   The requesting party, in turn, is
>   playing the acceptor role for the
>   responses. If responses get lost, they
>   must be resent by the responding party
>   and therefore they must also be cached
>   (and acknowledged). Both ends of a
>   reliable messaging session therefore
>   maintain separate caches for outbound
>   and inbound messages.

So yes, the same applies to the responses, as well - which works fine as long as we have a two-way communication like over NetTCP or HTTP - as mentioned in the article, it gets a bit trickier in case of a one-way operation - see the article for details.

Marc

Comment: Thank you very much! Does the same thing apply to server side and return values? Will update my question.

Comment: Thank you! I've just completed reading it. Will try to investigate my issue further.

Comment: And what about parameters disposing? Does it happen when ack was recieved? I did not find a lof of info about it :(

Comment: what do you mean by "parameter disposing"? When you send a request in WCF, the WCF runtime will take your parameters and serialize those into a message. This message is what's being stored - anything else is being discarded, as far as I know.

Comment: Thank you once again. Marc, I've added part of my ugly stack. It may clarify what I'm trying to solve.

Comment: Worked around the other way. Removed disposing altogether. Thanks for pointing me at "ordered" stuff.